# getting issues when interfacing plc and raspberry together

Tags: raspbian

hi im very new to this plc and raspberry. i've to do a project where i have to connect plc and raspberry and wanted to check whether the programming is working or not. im using PM554-t-ETh PLC. so can anybody help me with this. I need to be able to talk (ping and connect) with the PLCs hooked to the Pi.. but i couldnt able to do in this method or anybody knows different method.i have finished the plc programming and i need to try whether its working properly or not.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions, if you want to add more info edit your original question.